# Object.prototype using 'this'

Tags: javascript, object, methods, prototype

This might be basic, it might not be possible, I might be misunderstanding totally but I am a beginner trying to understand how adding methods to objects using Object.prototype works.

The best way to explain my question is to show firstly show the following:

```
Object.prototype.printHTML = function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
};
```

`this` seems to refer simply to Object.prototype.printHTML (alerting the HTML of exactly what is after the = sign in the above.

**My question is**, can you refer directly to the Object used?

so, the below would alert "Test Paragraph":

```
<body>
<p id='test'>Test Paragraph</p>

<script>
Object.prototype.printHTML = function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
};

document.getElementById("test").printHTML; //this would alert "Test Paragraph"
//currently alerts "function() {alert(this.innerHTML);}
</script>
</body>
```

I understand this example is pointless (because `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;` gives me exactly what I would need for this) but I am just trying to understand creating methods using Object.prototype and I cannot figure out how to access the Object the method is being run on.

Thanks

Comment: Simple, change `document.getElementById("test").printHTML` to `document.getElementById("test").printHTML()`

Comment: @CallumLinington thanks, how very beginnerish of me!

Comment: Accept the answer if i helped :)

Comment: Sorry, just come back on.  I tried accepting straight away but it didn't allow it.  Done now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close, instead do this

```
<body>
<p id='test'>Test Paragraph</p>

<script>
Object.prototype.printHTML = function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
};

document.getElementById("test").printHTML(); //<--- HERE WE ADD THE PARENTHESIS
//currently alerts "function() {alert(this.innerHTML);}
</script>
</body>
```

You were accessing `printHTML` as a property rather and a function and executing it. Hence why you got the function  as text.